# Determine stability of non autonomous system at the origin

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I am trying to determine the stability of the zero solution of the system
$x'=
\begin{bmatrix}
    -t      & 1 \\
     1      & -t 
   \end{bmatrix}x
$

Even though, a Liapunov method can only be applied to autonomous systems I was thinking we can use a similar approach as follows:

To show that the system is asymptotically stable at the point $x_0$ it is enough to show that it is stable and that

$$\displaystyle \lim_{t \to +\infty} |\phi(t,t_0)-x_0|=0 $$ for all $x \in U(x_0)$ for some neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$.

Then define $L(x(t),y(t))=x^2+y^2$ which would be the $|| \, .||^2$.

And if we show that $L'(x,y)<0$ along trajectories then $L(x,y)$ will be strictly decreasing continuous function and lower bounded by $0$ and therefore the limit condition mentioned above will be satisfied.

The problem is that this is not the case at least with $L$ the way I am defining it. 
So another option is that may be I need to find another norm where this does happen.

Does that sound like something we could do?

I tried $L(x,y)=ax^n+by^m$ but still I can't get that $L'<0$.

Is there any other approach someone can suggest?

Any help would be greatly appreciate it. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

**Stability:**
For $L(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ we have
$$
\dot L(x,y)=4xy-2t(x^2+y^2),
$$
which is negative definite for $t$ sufficiently large, independently of $x,y$, and so we are done with stability.

**Asymptotic stability:**
The determinant of any fundamental matrix is $\exp\int_0^t(-2s)\,ds=e^{-t^2}$ and so necessarily all solutions tend to the origin.

Comment: Use $2xy\le x^2+y^2$ to get $\dot L<0$ for $t>1$ independent of $(x,y)$.

Comment: For $x'=(-\tfrac{1}{2}t-1)x$, $y'=y$, the determinant of a fundamental matrix is $e^{-t^2}$, whereas the origin is unstable. Your second argument seems to be inconclusive (LutzL's is O.K.).

Comment: @JohnB And what about $x'=-x$, $y'=0$? The origin is stable but not asymptotically stable, and the determinant is $e^{-t}$.

Answer (score 2):

You get that all the matrices $A(t)=J-tI$ commute, where $I=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$, $J=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$, thus 
$$\exp(\int A(s)ds)=\exp(Jt-\frac12t^2I)=e^{-t^2/2}(\cosh(t)I+\sinh(t)J)$$ 
is a fundamental matrix of the LDE system and the solution can be written as
$$
x(t)=e^{-t^2/2}(\cosh(t)I+\sinh(t)J)x_0
$$
and the first factor falls, eventually, faster than the second factor grows.

Comment: I upvoted LuztL's answer yesterday, from 2 to 3.  Now I see that in the meanwhile someone downvoted it from 3 to 2.  Could the downvoter explain why he/she did so, please?